# Gitlab can replace artifactory?

Tags: gitlab, artifactory

on the gitlab home page https://about.gitlab.com/ : "Gitlab replaces artifactory"

But when I click on the link to have more information: "404 error".

Can gitlab really offers similar service as artifactory do ? (maven cache, binary repository etc..) ?

The goal is to simplify our architecture, if we can have one tool instead of 2 it would be great: gitlab and artifactory -> only gitlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, but there is active development to have Artifactory like functionality within GitLab, with Maven being the initial focus. You can see the progress in [gitlab-org/gitlab-ee#5811 (Add Maven support to our Artifact Repository)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/5811) and [gitlab-org&86 (Binary repository for Maven)](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/86).